# First character of full name not the username

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a task to write to file the list of login names, full names and home directories of all users whose first character of their full name (not login name) is "A" or "Z"(process the file
/etc/passwd).

I tried with

```
> cat /etc/passwd | grep -i '^A\|^Z' > ex.list
```

But it also outputs users who have first name starting with other letter than A or Z. How to change it ?

Comment: This will do: `getent passwd | awk -F: '$5 ~ /^[AZ]/{printf("%s\t%s\n", $5, $6)}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `getent` to obtain the `passwd` entries regardless if it is a local `/etc/passwd` file or a **N**etworked **I**nformation **S**ervice.
- Use `awk` to filter the desired user entries, then prints their real name and home directory properties.

```sh
getent passwd | awk -F: '$5 ~ /^[AZ]/{printf("%s\t%s\n", $5, $6)}'
```

- `awk -F:`: invoke `awk` with `:` as field delimiter.

The awk program itself

```
# Filter field 5 containing Real Name
# and regex match it starts with upper-case A or Z
$5 ~ /^[AZ]/{
  # For each selected entry
  # Print a tab formatted list with fields 5 and 6
  # witch contains the Real-Name and Home Directory
  printf("%s\t%s\n", $5, $6)
}
```